# Iterating through shapefile and appending each row separately to existing shapefile

Tags: arcpy, cursor, proximity

I am attempting to iterate through each row of a shapefile, run a process on it (finding the nearest point from each in_feature to the closest near_feature) and then appending each row to the near_features so they will be used on the following rows near analysis.

I am using ArcPy.

```
in_features = "Unserved_Sample"
near_features = "Served_Sample"
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)

for row in cursor:
    arcpy.Near_analysis(in_features, near_features)
    arcpy.management.Append(in_features, near_features)

del cursor
```

Comment: Youre right let me add it back in

Comment: Have you tried looking into the model builder capabilities?

Comment: I have, but I was also having trouble appending a selected row so I thought python might be easier.

Comment: Are you using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro or with ArcMap?